# Female guinea pig uterus infection, please help

Tags: health, defecation, infections, guinea-pigs

My female guinea pig Coco, 2 years old, recently had her sonography done and she was found to have uterus infection. We have two other female guinea pigs, and one of them previously too had a uterus infection and we got her uterus surgically removed and then after treatment she was fine.

So for Coco, we went to the same place and got her treated and removed her uterus as well. It's been 15 days since and she's still not quite recovered. It looks as if she's still in pain. She appears to be in a lot of discomfort when she poops and her feces appear to be very small. As of now, she hardly eats and is inactive as well. So we have to force feed her and keep her hydrated. The doctor said the infection has been in her body for few months and she is not able to put down the antibiotics in her body, so we might need to give her some injectible antibiotics and fluids.

I looked online and found out the condition of impacted bottoms for guinea pigs and it looks as if she's suffering from that (as in not eating, inactive and struggling to poop); however, I also know that happens mostly to males.

I just wanted some insights from other people too. Please help!

Comment: I understand your concern, but since this a Q&A style forum can you please formulate a clear question that helps us understand your problem better?

Comment: Every operation in the abdominal cavity can lead to constipation or - in the worst case - to a twisting of the intestine that blocks it completely. Since your guinea pig can still pass stool, the intestine is probably not twisted. Personally, I would go with the advice of the vet or get a second oppinion from a different vet if you don't trust the first one.